# Android Studio - setValue on Firebase with Quick Settings Tile in Lock Screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing an app that lets me control multiple things via Firebase Real Time Database. For example: I can switch a light on and off with the press of a button. The last feature I added was a Quick Settings Tile so turn said lamp on or off. To accomplish that I used TileService in combination with Firebase as seen below. This works fine, until the screen is locked for while. If I then click the tile, it turns on or off, however it does not update the Firebase database. I suppose the phone falls into sleep mode and keeps the Tile from using internet connection? To clarify: the only thing that does not work is updating the firebase value/update the Icon when I manually change the firebase value online.
This is how the Database gets referenced:

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
final DatabaseReference tripodstatus=myRef.child("tripod").child("status");
```

This is the onStartListening code:

```
    @Override
public void onStartListening(){
    tripodstatus.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            int val = Integer.parseInt(value);
            if(val == 0){
                readstate=false;
            }
            else{
                readstate=true;
            }
            refresh(readstate);
            Log.d("file", "Value is: " + val + readstate);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = (CharSequence)databaseError;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    });
```

And this is what it does when I click it (turning it off is the same basically)

```
        getQsTile().setState(STATE_ACTIVE);
        Icon icon = Icon.createWithResource(getApplicationContext(),statusImages[1]);
        getQsTile().setIcon(icon);
        getQsTile().updateTile();
        tripodstatus.setValue("1");
```

I think the function to turn it on gets called (since the Tile switches to active) but it somehow failes to update Firebase. I'd highly appreciate any help on how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you not changing the icon right inside `onDataChange`? Have you tried this way?

Comment: That might work but I don't think it'll address the issue. To clarify: I expect following command to be run when I press the quick tile "tripodstatus.setValue("1");".
However this value gets set in Firebase only when I unlock my phone. All the other commands get executed as expected.I have the wake permission in my manifest.

Comment: @AlexMamo (I don't know if it is common here to tag people while answering, so I'll just tag you now)

Comment: It is common. Why are you not changing the icon right inside onDataChange? Have you tried this way?

Comment: @AlexMamo as I said, this doesn't address the issue. The issue is, that the Quick Tile cannot update the Firebase or recieve firebase updates, when my phone is locked. (probably can't access internet or can't establish firebase connection when locked)